# debugging/learning javascript using Visual Studio Code and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code to learn/test javascript.

To enable debugging, I installed Node.js and chose "node" in launch.json

The thing I do not understand is that my code behaves differently whether I use break points or not...

```
var some_array = ["toto1", "titi9", "toto2", "titi33", "ratitit"];

console.log("A", some_array);

some_array.push(some_array.length);

console.log("B", some_array);

some_array.push(some_array.length);

console.log("C", some_array);

// filtering an array with a (lambda) callback function
console.log("D", some_array.filter(thing => thing.length > 5));

console.log("E", some_array.includes("titi9"))
```

If I do not put any breakpoint, press < F5 >, then I see messages "A" and "E" in the Debug Console. No idea what happens to "B" to "D"...

If I put a breakpoint on the last line, press < F5 >, then I see all messages to "D", and then "E" if I press < F5 > again...

In fact, I get slightly different behaviours depending on where I put my breakpoint (or even a logpoint).

Does this make some sense???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add the following line to the lauch.json file

```
"outputCapture": "std",
```